# Emacs ECB methods window not updating

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-ecb

So I do have Emacs 24.3.1 installed, and from 24 onwards it comes with CEDET. I installed ECB through list-packages and everything seems to work - except methods window refreshing.

When I open a file, all methods are displayed and I can jump to them no problem. But the issue is that they never refresh without restarting Emacs. I have experimented with almost every related variable I could find and nothing works.
I am desperately looking for solution, sice it pretty much nullifies methods window usability when I'm expanding the project.

I have these variables added, no Emacs errors, but it still won't refresh - neither after saving, nor after some idle time.

```
(setq auto-update-methods-after-save 1)
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
```

I am new to this, so I may be missing some obvious solution. Could anyone help me? I can provide any configuration file or info you'll need.

EDIT: Of course tried C-c . r , no results.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had same problem. The methods list got updated after I do:
1) revert-buffer
2) ecb-rebuild-methods-buffer (C-c . r)

The fact that just p.2 is not enough seems to be a bug though.